# Monorepo Shared Package not Found when Running Docker-Compose

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo set up with [lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) and yarn [workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/).
Everything is written in typescript and compiled into javascript.

But there is an issue with sharing packages when running the monorepo via `docker-compose`.

I've created a small repo, which mimics the behavior: https://github.com/skatestyle/stackoverflow-monorepo-dependencies.

---

Basically there is a `@root/common` and a `@root/server` package. The `server` imports the `common`. Everything works fine when running `node packages/server/lib/index.js`. (**Please note, that you need to run `yarn bootstrap` and `yarn build` before starting**)

But when running my docker-compose file via `docker-compose up --build`, I get the following error:

```
Building server
Step 1/4 : FROM node:alpine
 ---> d4edda39fb81
Step 2/4 : COPY . /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d96b00510d47
Step 3/4 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f112f411cdfb
Step 4/4 : CMD node lib/index.js
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 87a4cea60811
Successfully built 87a4cea60811
Successfully tagged stackoverflow-monorepo-dependecies_server:latest
Starting stackoverflow-monorepo-dependecies_server_1 ... done
Attaching to stackoverflow-monorepo-dependecies_server_1
server_1  | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626
server_1  |     throw err;
server_1  |     ^
server_1  | 
server_1  | Error: Cannot find module '@root/common'
server_1  | Require stack:
server_1  | - /src/lib/index.js
server_1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:623:15)
server_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
server_1  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
server_1  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
server_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/src/lib/index.js:7:16)
server_1  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
server_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
server_1  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
server_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
server_1  |     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10) {
server_1  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
server_1  |   requireStack: [ '/src/lib/index.js' ]
server_1  | }
```

And yes, I need to use `docker-compose`, because my real project has more servers running.

The error probably lies in my `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml`, but I can't find it.

Thanks in advance for every help!

Comment: Maybe the image node:alpine used on you Dockerfile doesn't contain module @root/common try use another image "node:8" for example.

Comment: Great idea, but it didn't work (same issue)

Comment: On you docker composer you create volume  
 `- ./packages/server:/src` the structure inside container will be different to your local.
try  :   
`version: '3'

services:
  server:
    build: ./packages/server
    volumes:
      - ./:/src
`
and on dockerfile:   
`FROM node:alpine

COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src

CMD ["node","packages/server/lib/index.js"]`

Comment: This one worked! I'll give you the bounty when you write an answer :)

Comment: You can marked it resolve if it works ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On you docker-compose you create volume

> ./packages/server:/src

The structure inside container will be different to your local. try :

```
version: '3'
services: 
   server: 
      build: ./packages/server 
      volumes: - ./:/src
```

and on dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
CMD ["node","packages/server/lib/index.js"]
```

Hope it helps