# How to run Docker using shared packages?

Tags: docker, monorepo, nomachine-nx

Firstly, the development environment is as follows:

1. Using Yarn Berry for zero-installation
2. Managing a monorepo with Nx
3. The folder structure looks like this.

Given such interdependent monorepos, how should I configure Docker?

Here's the folder structure:

```
packages
|-- A
|  |-- package.json (name : @mono/A)  
|
|        .... 
|-- B // B has a dependency on A 
|  |-- package.json (name : @mono/B)  
|
|
services
|-- C // C has a dependency on B 
|  |-- package.json (name : @mono/C)  // main service based on next.js 
|
|
docker-compose.yml
package.json
nx.json
```

In the docker-compose.yml located in the root, I wrote it like this,

```
version: "3"
services:

  A:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
      context: ./packages/A
    image: A:latest

  B:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
      context: ./packages/B
    depends_on:
      - A

  C:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./services/C/Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./
    image: C:latest
    volumes:
      - /app/services/C/node_modules
      - ./services/web:/app/services/C
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - C
```

The Dockerfile in the A folder is as follows:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

WORKDIR /packages/A
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN yarn cache clean --all && yarn install

COPY . .
```

The Dockerfile in the B folder is as follows:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

WORKDIR /packages/theme 
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN yarn cache clean --all && yarn install
COPY . . 

FROM base AS runner


WORKDIR /packages/them
COPY --from=dep /packages/them .
CMD ["yarn", "build"]
```

And B's package.json

```
{
  "name": "@mono/B",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
   ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mono/A": "workspace:^",
 
  }
}
```

but the problem arises when building B - an error pops up saying '@mono/A module not found.' B relies on the functionality of @mono/A and it's essential in this scenario like below.

```
0.331 [1/4] Resolving packages...
1.112 info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/packages/theme/yarn-error.log".
1.112 error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@mono%2fA: Not found".
```

How should I write each Dockerfile and docker-compose files?

I've attempted to follow [similar questions and their solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656435/monorepo-shared-package-not-found-when-running-docker-compose), but unfortunately, none have resolved my issue.

```
  B:
    build: ./packages/B
    volumes:
      - ./:/src  // it didn't work
    depends_on:
      - A
```

If you need more resources, my Discord Id is `do.mang`